# Cannot find type definition file for 'node' when update TS to 5.1.6

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular 16 project I try to update typescript to latest version (5.1.6) which is compatible if I read the [Angular website](https://angular.io/guide/versions). The problem is that I have the following error when I try to `build-watch` :

```
> opencapture@3.0.0 build-watch
> ng build --configuration development --watch

⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...    TypeScript compiler options "target" and "useDefineForClassFields" are set to "ES2022" and "false" respectively by the Angular CLI. To control ECMA version and features use the Browerslist configuration. For more information, see https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-browser-compatibility
    NOTE: You can set the "target" to "ES2022" in the project's tsconfig to remove this warning.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Error: error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point of type library 'node' specified in compilerOptions



✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Error: error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point of type library 'node' specified in compilerOptions
```

Here is my tsconfig.json :

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es2021",
        "module": "es2022",
        "declaration": false,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2022",
            "dom"
        ],
        "types": [
            "node"
        ]
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "strictTemplates": true,
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true,
        "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
        "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false
    }
}
```

My tsconfig.app.json

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
        "types": [ "node" ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "../node_modules/@types",
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "./main.ts",
        "./polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

And here is my package.json (before typescript update) :

```
{
    "name": "opencapture",
    "version": "3.0.0",
    "license": "GPL-3.0",
    "author": "Edissyum Consulting <nathan.cheval@edissyum.com>",
    "description": "Open-Capture is the one and only 100% Open Source intelligent capture management",
    "scripts": {
        "check-update": "ncu",
        "build-prod": "ng build --configuration production",
        "build-watch": "ng build --configuration development --watch",
        "upgrade-all-packages-ncu": "ncu -u && npm run reload-packages",
        "reload-packages": "rm -Rf node_modules && rm -f package-lock.json && npm i",
        "extract-translations": "ngx-translate-extract --input ./src/frontend/ --output ./src/assets/i18n/frontend/*.json --clean --sort --format namespaced-json --marker _"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@ngstack/code-editor": "^5.0.0",
        "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^20.4.1",
        "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^7.0.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "ng-sortgrid": "^16.0.0",
        "ngx-file-drag-drop": "^7.0.0",
        "ngx-mat-select-search": "^7.0.2",
        "ngx-toastr": "^17.0.2",
        "remove-accents": "^0.4.4",
        "svg-country-flags": "^1.2.10",
        "tinymce": "^6.6.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.4",
        "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "^0.1601.4",
        "@angular-eslint/builder": "16.1.0",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "16.1.0",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "16.1.0",
        "@angular-eslint/schematics": "16.1.0",
        "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "16.1.0",
        "@angular-material-extensions/select-country": "^8.1.0",
        "@angular/animations": "~16.1.5",
        "@angular/cdk": "^16.1.5",
        "@angular/cli": "~16.1.4",
        "@angular/common": "~16.1.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "~16.1.5",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~16.1.5",
        "@angular/core": "~16.1.5",
        "@angular/forms": "~16.1.5",
        "@angular/material": "^16.1.5",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^16.1.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~16.1.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~16.1.5",
        "@angular/router": "~16.1.5",
        "@bartholomej/ngx-translate-extract": "^8.0.2",
        "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract-marker": "^1.0.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.0",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "@schematics/angular": "^16.1.4",
        "@types/d3-scale": "^4.0.3",
        "@types/d3-selection": "^3.0.5",
        "@types/d3-shape": "^3.1.1",
        "@types/node": "^20.4.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "6.1.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "6.1.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "eslint": "^8.45.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "latest",
        "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "latest",
        "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "latest",
        "jquery": "^3.7.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.26",
        "rxjs": "~7.8.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "typescript": "~5.0.4",
        "zone.js": "~0.13.1"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Do you have `@types/node` installed ?

Comment: Yes, I update my post to add my package.json

Comment: It's probably because of this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-1/#explicit-typeroots-disables-upward-walks-for-node_modules-types

Comment: Hi @PitaJ I check your link and I think my tsconfig.app.json already have the node declaration :/

Comment: It's not about the node declaration. It's about `typeRoots`

Comment: I check it and it's already declared in my tsconfig.app.json (I add it in my post)

Comment: Did you find the solution @Nathan30? I have had to downgrade to version 4.9 of TypeScript but it is not the best solution

Comment: Are you using Yarn 3 PnP? If so, TypeScript 5.1 appears to not be compatible with it. It [requires `types`/`typeRoots`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-1/#explicit-typeroots-disables-upward-walks-for-node_modules-types), and without actual `node_modules` directory it won’t work (even though Yarn installs a patched version of TS for PnP support, it appears that 5.1 is broken anyway). If you downgrade to 5.0.*, it should work.

Comment: @Alba I manage to fix this. I'm not sure to remember well, but try to change the typesRoot to :        

"typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types",
            "../node_modules/@types",
            "../../node_modules/@types"
        ]